# How to use JavaDB as SQL parser

Tags: java, sql, javadb

About a month ago I built an application that used zSQL as the SQL parser to parse SQL. However, just few days ago, a heavy duty user sent in  a multi row insert statement which zSQL doesn't support. This is the sample:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstCol, SecondCol)
SELECT 'First' ,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Second' ,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Third' ,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fourth' ,4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Fifth' ,5
```

Then I found this link: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2008/11/23/stand-alone-sql-parser-java, it says "With a simple fix, Rick Hillegas has ensured that developers can have access to a powerful SQL parser that comes with Apache/Derby". However, I can't find any relevant documentation to achieve this.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try clicking on the link 'a simple fix' in that post on java.net? The first comment shows how to run the tool. If you read [the code to ASTParser.java](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12417626/ASTParser.java), you can see the code you need to write to use the parser.

Comment: @hemu: Post that as a new question. This is not the place to discuss it.

Answer (score 1):

The link you have given uses Internal APIs of Derby, it also requires the debug version of Derby.

As of version 10.10, it still cannot be used as a general SQL Parser as it requires the tables in the SQL to exist - not a good sign that their parser is separate enough for use as a parser! (And in general a worrying sign that their architecture is crap)